# Facebook Fb.ui select only one friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a small board game for Facebook, and I need a way to send an app request to only one friend. I will use

*FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', to: '1234', message: 'A request especially for one person.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});*

But I need a way for the user to select a friend an only one from his list. Is there a way to pop the friend-selector and restrict the maximum selection to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use  "max_recipients" parameter

```
  FB.ui(
            {
              method  : 'apprequests',
              message : 'A request especially for one person.', 
          to: '1234', 
          max_recipients:1,
              data: 'tracking information for the user'

                    }

          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own similar widget that lists all of a users friends using the graph api to retrieve all of their friends by calling /me/friends.  Then let the user select a friend and clicking some kind of invite button next to the friend that calls this:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', to: '4', message: 'A request especially for one person.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```

And just set the 'to' parameter to the one user selected.